# Mock recipientList and reading from a directory

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-camel

How can I mock the following code:

```
from(directoryPath + "?recursive=true)
    .routeId("Test")
    .process(testProcessor)
    .recipientList(simple("${header.nameOfMyDestination}")
```

The header will be set in my processor.
I have tried multiple ways, this seemed like the most "valid", but it's not working. I have created a structure for the directories in my resources (I am using Spring Boot) and tried like this:

```
camelContext.getRouteDefinition("Test")
    .adviceWith(camelContext, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
     @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            replaceFromWith("file://" + sourceDirectory + "?recursive=true");
            weaveByToString("RecipientList*")
               .recipientList(simple("mock" + "${header.nameOfMyDestination}"));
 }
```

I will have multiple outgoing endpoints. When I assert my mock endpoints, it fails. 0 messages all the time. And the strange part is: if I don't have a file in my source directory (only in subdirectories) camel doesn't find it. (This behaviour is only in tests).

Comment: You need a colon in the mock endpoint, eg "mock:"

Comment: I have the semicolon in the second string: recipientList(simple(“mock”+”:${headed.nameOfMyDestination}”).  I am able to debug the processor I can see that the header is created correctly, but I don’t know where this message goes, seems like I cannot mock the recipientList

Comment: What Camel version do you use? And have you tried with weaveByType

Comment: I am using 2.20.1, I have found the problem,  the mocking of the route is correct, what was not correct was how I defined the directory structure in the resource, IDK why the files were not correctly read. Now I have switched to create the directory structure in the code before each test and it is working.